# How to debug Angular errors?

Tags: angularjs

I'm starting to learn Angular and a number of times I have seen errors in Chrome's console that appear to be really ambiguous. For instance that screen grab below

[image: Imgur]

How am I mean't to be able to track down what the issue is?

Comment: In this case you probably did not load all required .js files, or the definition of dependencies in your app/module is incorrect/incomplete

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Chrome anyway; definitely consider installing the Batarang extension for Angular.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en-US

It let's you examine the $scope of all your controllers, among other things.